# dired+ does not launch automatically

Tags: emacs, dired

The built-in Dired is launched when I type <kbd>C-x d</kbd>. [`dired+`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) is loaded because I can run `diredp-*` commands, but `dired+` is only launched *after* I have run a `diredp` command. What is the problem? I am using Emacs 24.1 and I installed `dired+` through the package manager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dired+ is not loaded. All the functions you see are autoloaded. This means that as soon as you call one of those functions emacs knows it needs to read diredp.el. Once it reads that file, it overrides the default dired and makes everything work.

To fix your problem, just `(require 'diredp)` in your `.emacs`.

Comment: There is `File error: Cannot open load file, diredp` if I add `(require 'diredp)` or `(requre 'dired+)`.

Comment: Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127109/emacs-24-package-system-initialization-problems/11140619#11140619. You need to do `(package-initialize)` before requiring some packages.

Comment: right. I have `(packagge-initialize)` in my .emacs file, but forgot that I need to put `(require 'dired+)` after it. Thanks. Problem solved.

Comment: I believe this answer should be: `To fix your problem, just (require 'dired+) in your .emacs`. That works for me. Trying `(require 'diredp)` seems to fail because there is no `diredp` installed (it is `dired+`)