# Loading packages installed through 'package.el' in Emacs24

Tags: emacs, elisp, dot-emacs, emacs24

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Emacs 24 Package System Initialization Problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127109/emacs-24-package-system-initialization-problems)

I am using Emacs 24. I have the ELPA and Marmalade repos added. Using 'package' I installed 'auto-complete'. I have the following lines added to my init.el:

```
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(ac-config-default)
```

When I start Emacs, I get the error

> File error: Cannot open load file, auto-complete-config

But then I use

> M-x load-file

and load the same ~/.emacs.d/init.el file, it then works fine with the prompt saying

> Loading /home/user/.emacs.d/init.el (source)...done

How is the usual loading different from the 'M-x load-file' command? In the start of the init.el file I do the following, is this somehow effecting the package from loading.

> (add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d") 
>   (load "custom_code")

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**As mentioned in the comment below: The answer by phils to the [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127109) is probably more helpful than this one**

This almost certainly means that your `init.el` file is getting run before the code that sorts out the packages for `package.el`. The latter code adds the directory with the auto-complete library to your load path.

I'm still using ELPA, rather than package.el. With elpa, there's a snippet that looks like this that gets installed at the bottom of your `.emacs`.

```
;;; This was installed by package-install.el.
;;; This provides support for the package system and
;;; interfacing with ELPA, the package archive.
;;; Move this code earlier if you want to reference
;;; packages in your .emacs.
(when
    (load
     (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/elpa/package.el"))
  (package-initialize))
```

As the comment suggests, you probably want to put your equivalent `package.el` initialization code before the stuff that loads `init.el`.

Finally: I notice you mention adding `.emacs.d` to your `load-path`. The Emacs load path is not recursive, so that probably won't do what you need (assuming that your libraries live in subdirectories). Years ago, I wrote this snippet to load up various libraries of elisp code that I'd written. You might find it useful. (Obviously, it'll only work on unixy systems with a shell and a find command. It's reasonably slow, but this seems to be `shell-command-to-string`, which takes several milliseconds even running "echo hello" or the like)

```
(defun find-elisp-dirs (dir)
  "Find all directories below DIR containing elisp sources, ignoring those"
  (split-string
   (shell-command-to-string
    (format "find %s -iname '*.el' -printf '%%h\\n' | sort -u"
            (expand-file-name dir t)))))
```

Comment: great, adding (package-initialize) in the start of 'init.el' did the job. Thanks.

Comment: See the answer by phils in the thread this thread is a duplicate of for a proper solution; `(package-initialize)` might not really be the right way to fix this.