# Auto install emacs packages with MELPA

Tags: emacs, elisp, package

I want to declare all packages that I want to use in emacs in a *init.el* file. I wonder if its possible to load the missing packages with e.g. MELPA when I startup emacs without going through the list and mark the ones I want to install?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

### New answer:

While my original answer is still valid, I now use the method [suggested by Jordon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21342883/354577). [`use-package`](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package) is a fantastic tool for tidy Emacs configurations. In fact, I was already using it for clean package loading when I wrote my original answer.

At that time, I neglected to read all the way to [the bottom of its README](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package#for-packageel-users), and therefore didn't realize that it could handle package installation as well:

> ### For `package.el` users
>
> You can use `use-package` to load packages from ELPA with package.el. This is particularly useful if you share your .emacs between several machines; the relevant packages will download automatically once placed in your .emacs. The `:ensure` key will install the package automatically if it is not already present:
>
> ```
> (use-package tex-site
>   :ensure auctex)
> ```

After loading `package.el` and initializing my package repositories, my configuration contains

```
(if (not (package-installed-p 'use-package))
    (progn
      (package-refresh-contents)
      (package-install 'use-package)))

(require 'use-package)
```

and subsequently many snippets like this:

```
;;; Expand-region
(use-package expand-region
  :ensure expand-region
  :bind ("C-=" . er/expand-region))
```

If you find this information useful, please give Jordon an upvote.

### Original answer:

Have a look at [Cask](http://cask.github.io/) and [Pallet](https://github.com/rdallasgray/pallet), which work together to solve this problem.

From the Cask website:

> Cask for Emacs is what Bundler is to Ruby. It aims to make ELPA dependency management in Emacs painless (as painless as it can be). This includes both your local Emacs installation and Emacs package development.

After [installing Cask](http://cask.github.io/installation/), you'll need to add something like this to your Emacs configuration:

```
(require 'cask)
(cask-initialize)
```

Cask defines a doman-specific language for elisp dependencies. For installing packages, you'll need something [like what is outlined here](http://cask.github.io/examples/):

```
(source melpa)

(depends-on "auto-complete")
(depends-on "dash")
(depends-on "f")
(depends-on "flycheck")
(depends-on "helm")
(depends-on "magit")
(depends-on "popup")
(depends-on "projectile")
(depends-on "s")
(depends-on "smartparens")
(depends-on "yasnippet")
```

Note that this does not go into your Emacs config file, but rather into `~/.emacs.d/Cask`.

Pallet updates the Cask file with packages installed interactively, e.g. via `M-x package-list-packages`, so you don't have to manually maintain the above file.

Comment: It seems Cask + Pallet is not yet supported on windows platform and @work I have to use it, so I can not use this solution.

Comment: @Chris How do you handle package dependencies?

Comment: @Martinsos, the underlying `package.el` system handles dependencies. Have a look at, for instance, [`cider` in MELPA stable](http://stable.melpa.org/#/cider). When installing `cider`, any missing dependencies are also installed.

Comment: @Chris thank you for answer! What about https://github.com/edvorg/req-package then, what is that good for, if dependencies are resolved automatically?

Comment: @Martinsos, I've never seen `req-package` before now. I don't see what the benefit is over `use-package` with `:ensure`, aside from some minor syntax sugar. I may be missing something, though... The [`el-get` bit](https://github.com/edvorg/req-package#el-get) is moderately interesting.

Comment: @Chris Thanks, I will ask more about it on req-package repo then. Maybe it was more useful when use-package did not have `:ensure` yet.

Answer (score 34):

All of these answers will work, but I would highly recommend using `use-package`

found here: https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package

use-package not only will automatically install your missing packages, but it greatly simplifies your init.el.

Here's an example from my init.el

```
;; initial package setup
(push "path/to/use-package" load-path)
(require 'use-package)
(require 'package)
(mapc (lambda(p) (push p package-archives))
      '(("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/")
        ("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/")))
(package-refresh-contents)
(package-initialize)

;; this will install undo-tree if it's not there
;; and it will set it up how I want
(use-package undo-tree
  :init (global-undo-tree-mode 1)
  :bind (("C-c j" . undo-tree-undo)
         ("C-c k" . undo-tree-redo)
         ("C-c l" . undo-tree-switch-branch)
         ("C-c ;" . undo-tree-visualize))
  :ensure t)
```

Take a look at my init.el here: https://github.com/jordonbiondo/.emacs.d/blob/master/init.el

each use-package block will install the specified package if it is not there, and it encapsulates all my additional setup for packages like keybindings, hooks, and other customizations.

Comment: the (package-refresh-contents) function take 'forever' each time I launch emacs even if all my libs are already downloaded. Can't we tell use-package to do it only when needed ?

Comment: By "when needed" I assume you mean "only when a package needs to be upgraded", which this doesn't really work because you don't know if something can be upgraded unless you run package-refresh-contents. what you can do is scan package archives and run package-refresh-contents only when the archives are <some-number> days old or something.

If everything is installed to your liking, you can just comment out the package-refresh-contents.

Answer (score 7):

A bit of code in your init file can do that quite easily:

```lisp
(setq my-onlinep nil)
(unless
    (condition-case nil
        (delete-process
         (make-network-process
          :name "my-check-internet"
          :host "elpa.gnu.org"
          :service 80))
      (error t))
  (setq my-onlinep t))

(setq my-packages
      '(ack-and-a-half
        ac-nrepl
        ... more packages here ...
        web-mode
        yaml-mode
        yari
        yasnippet))

(when my-onlinep
  (package-refresh-contents)
  (cl-loop for p in my-packages
           unless (package-installed-p p)
           do (package-install p)))
```

The online check is not really needed but helps to avoid getting a stuck Emacs startup when there is no internet connection.

For my full config see here: http://steckerhalter.co.vu/steckemacs.html#sec-2-5

Comment: it looks like that URL is down. Could you redirect?

Answer (score 5):

In addition to excellent options suggested above you may also want take a look at [el-get](https://github.com/dimitri/el-get). I use it for my emacs setup and have been very happy with it.

**How is it different?**

Two main advantages of el-get are

1) It can fetch packages from variety of sources, the website lists the following possible sources

> github, emacswiki, GNU ELPA or Marmalade, privately hosted pages, git, bzr, CVS etc

2) It can be used to run OS commands like `make` if required during package installation. This makes installation of packages that have non-elisp parts easier, eg. [emacs-jedi](http://tkf.github.io/emacs-jedi/), ropemacs etc

**Installing el-get**

Installation is pretty simple you will need to add the following bootstrap code given at their website to your init file.

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/el-get/el-get")

(unless (require 'el-get nil 'noerror)
  (with-current-buffer
      (url-retrieve-synchronously
       "https://raw.github.com/dimitri/el-get/master/el-get-install.el")
    (goto-char (point-max))
    (eval-print-last-sexp)))

(el-get 'sync)
```

This will install `el-get` if it is not already installed.

**Installing packages**

You can then declare the packages you want to install and let `el-get` install them

```
;; List of packages you want to install
(defvar my-packages '(auto-complete flycheck smart-parens...))
;; This will install any package from my-packages which is not already installed
(el-get 'sync my-packages)
```

OR

You can always install packages manually by doing `el-get-install <package-name> RET`, I doubt you will want to install your dozens of different packages this way but it is possible.

**Updating packages**

Updating packages is simply a matter of doing `el-get-update` to update a specific package or `el-get-update-all` to update all the installed packages.

Comment: I think it is not needed at all and you do yourself a favor by  sticking to standard package managers.

Comment: @nicolas I disagree with you so strongly that I wrote [yet another package manager for Emacs](https://github.com/raxod502/straight.el). It comes with a [list of reasons why `package.el` is terrible](https://github.com/raxod502/straight.el#advantages-of-straightel)!

Comment: And a list of reason for the 10 or so other package managers. I am not saying there are not better solution. Clearly nix-style/functional dependencies are great. Only that it would be an improvement if  half-baked solutions did die a fast death.

Comment: For every 1000 encouragement for unprincipled unspecified half finished loose piece of code to rely onto, i think it would be reasonable to have 1 warning to stick to the 2/3/4/.. serious approaches with reliable design choice and complete implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14838150/245173.  The code will automatically install missing packages, but won't update existing ones, so only the first startup is slow.

Answer (score 0):

I liked @steckerhalter's answer because it doesn't require any package installation. I'm building upon it here with the following improvements:

- looking at `package-selected-packages` variables so you don't have to specify the packages manually. This variable is populated by `custom-set-variables` when you install a package via the package manager.
- do the network check only if there are packages not installed.

  ```lisp
  (let ((not-installed-packages 
         (seq-remove 'package-installed-p package-selected-packages)))

    (when (consp not-installed-packages)

      (setq my-onlinep nil)
      (unless
          (condition-case nil
              (delete-process
               (make-network-process
                :name "my-check-internet"
                :host "elpa.gnu.org"
                :service 80))
            (error t))
        (setq my-onlinep t))

      (when my-onlinep
        (package-refresh-contents)
        (dolist (p not-installed-packages)
          (package-install p)))

      (let ((still-not-installed-packages 
             (seq-remove 'package-installed-p package-selected-packages)))
        (if (consp still-not-installed-packages)
            (message "Still not installed: %s" still-not-installed-packages)
          (message "Successfully installed: %s" not-installed-packages)))
      ))
  ```