# Emacs 24: Unable to find theme file for `solarized-dark.

Tags: macos, emacs, themes

I am on Mac 10.9.5 using Emacs 24.4

Following the instruction in here: https://github.com/sellout/emacs-color-theme-solarized , I downloaded the `emacs-color-theme-solarized` directory and added it to my Emacs custom-theme-load-path. That directory (`Emacs` was installed with `Macports`) looks like this :

```
 ls /opt/local/share/emacs/24.4/etc/themes/
 adwaita-theme.el            light-blue-theme.el         tsdh-dark-theme.el
 deeper-blue-theme.el        manoj-dark-theme.el         tsdh-light-theme.el
 dichromacy-theme.el         misterioso-theme.el         wheatgrass-theme.el
 emacs-color-theme-solarized tango-dark-theme.el         whiteboard-theme.el
 leuven-theme.el             tango-theme.el              wombat-theme.el
```

where `emacs-color-theme-solarized` is the directory. Then I added `(load-theme 'solarized-dark t)` to my `.emacs` file and when I re-initiate `emacs` I get the error: `Unable to find theme file for 'solarized-dark` .

I have tried to move all file within the `emacs-color-theme-solarized` directory directly into the `/opt/local/share/emacs/24.4/etc/themes/` directory, so that:

```
ls /opt/local/share/emacs/24.4/etc/themes/
LICENSE                      leuven-theme.el              tango-dark-theme.el
README.md                    light-blue-theme.el          tango-theme.el
adwaita-theme.el             makepkg.sh                   tsdh-dark-theme.el
color-theme-solarized-pkg.el manoj-dark-theme.el          tsdh-light-theme.el
color-theme-solarized.el     misterioso-theme.el          wheatgrass-theme.el
deeper-blue-theme.el         solarized-dark-theme.el      whiteboard-theme.el
dichromacy-theme.el          solarized-definitions.el     wombat-theme.el
emacs-color-theme-solarized  solarized-light-theme.el
```

follow the same process and obtained the same result. Finally, I read here: [Emacs 24 Package System Initialization Problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127109/emacs-24-package-system-initialization-problems/11140619#11140619) that a possible solution is adding the following two lines at the beginning of my `.emacs` file:

```
(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)
(package-initialize)
```

So I did and obtained the same result. Even loading the theme manually: `load-theme` and then `solarized-dark` is not solving the issue. It seems like any changes done to that directory are ignored by `.emacs`.

By the way, I also tried to add `(add-to-list 'load-path " /opt/local/share/emacs/24.4/etc/themes")` to my `.emacs` file as well as `(add-to-list 'load-path " ~/emacs.d/themes")`, and it was, also, unsuccessful.

In case is of any use, any of the themes that come with the instalation, e.g `(load-theme 'tsdh-dark t)`, work perfectly

Any ideas of how to solve this issue for the solarized theme?

thanks and happy new year!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Emacs 24 includes [`package.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ELPA), and I strongly recommend using that to install packages whenever possible. Versions of the Solarized theme are available from [MELPA Stable](http://stable.melpa.org/), [MELPA](http://melpa.org/), and [Marmalade](https://marmalade-repo.org/).

If you haven't used any of these package repositories yet, you'll need to add one by putting something like this in your init file:

```
(require 'package)
(package-initialize)

(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa-stable" . "http://stable.melpa.org/packages/") t)
```

Then use `M-x package-list-packages`, search for `color-theme-sanityinc-solarized`, mark it for installation with `i` and then install marked packages with `x`. I find this package list interface very handy for discovering new packages.

Packages installed this way generally go into `~/.emacs.d/elpa/`, e.g. `~/.emacs.d/elpa/color-theme-solarized-2.27/`. This should automatically be added to your `custom-theme-load-path`, which is required for `load-theme` to work.

Note that this particular version includes two themes *prefixed with the package maintainer's name*, so you'll have to do something like

```
(load-theme 'sanityinc-solarized-dark)  ; or
(load-theme 'sanityinc-solarized-light)
```

to make the theme load. Interactively, `load-theme` supports tab completion, which is probably the best way to see what installed themes are actually called.

As an aside, you might also want to look into tools for [automating the `package.el` install process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21064916/auto-install-emacs-packages-with-melpa/21065066), which is especially handy if you work on multiple machines.

Comment: I have done so, and the package is installed, thanks Chris. However, when I type `(load-theme 'solarized-dark t)` I still get the exact same error. Also, where is the package installed? how can I point to it?

Comment: I have been able to do it through `M-x color-theme-sanityinc-solarized-dark`. But ideally I would prefer to do it from the `.emacs` file.

Comment: In any case Chris, I just managed to do it manually (the `load-theme` command did not work). Using `M-x color-theme-sanityinc-solarized-dark` and then editing a little bit the `.emacs` file (given the fact that I had a series of `custom-set-faces` that I had to adapt). Thanks for the help. Problem solved!

Comment: @Javier, I have updated my answer to specify where ELPA packages are stored and clarify that this package's themes aren't actually called `solarized-dark` and `solarized-light`, which is probably why your call to `load-theme` failed.

Comment: Many thanks Chris, it does work (silly me!). Perfect. All set up for proper coding ;)