# Having trouble getiting Tomorrow theme to work in Emacs

Tags: emacs

I have only recently started to use emacs. I have succesffully used a couple of different themes, but am having trouble getting [Tomorrow](https://github.com/purcell/color-theme-sanityinc-tomorrow) to work.

Here's what I have done:

The .el files are in ~/.emacs.d/themes/

my-init.el:

```
(add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path "~/.emacs.d/themes/")
(require 'color-theme-sanityinc-tomorrow)
(load-theme 'color-theme-sanityinc-tomorrow-night t)
```

I load this in .emacs by doing

```
(add-hook 'after-init-hook '(lambda ()
                  (load "~/.emacs.d/my-noexternals.el")
                  (load "~/.emacs.d/my-init.el") ))
```

When I reload emacs I see `eval-buffer: Cannot open load file: no such file or directory, color-theme-sanityinc-tomorrow`.

Comment: Assuming you have Emacs version 24 or later (check with `M-x version RET` I _strongly_ recommend learning to use `package.el` for installing things. For example, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/27721215/354577 for a question and answer about installing themes

Comment: What if I'm using Emacs 23?

Comment: Then you should consider upgrading to Emacs 24 :-). That's only partly a joke; there are some really great improvements from 23 to 24. If you're going to continue using version 23 you might want to consider [installing `package.el` manually](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/ELPA#toc10). It does support Emacs 23, but it doesn't come with it.

Comment: I would very much like to upgrade, but it seems like this is not possible on Scientific Linux 6.5. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If color-theme-sanityinc-tomorrow.el is in ~/.emacs.d/themes/ you need to had:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/themes/")
```

before the require.

Regards