# Information about Emacs package sources and updates

Tags: emacs

I often use `M-x list-packages` to [manage my Emacs packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836958/updating-packages-in-emacs). When an update comes out for a package, I am offered the possibility to upgrade. However, it is unclear from the default menu what exactly **changed** in the package. Is there any way to find out, for a given package update, what are the **release notes** or main changes?

More generally, how can I find the **repository**  or **source** that holds the code for a given package update? Does ELPA/MELPA keep track of this information somehow?

For example, for the packages  `bookmark+` or `multi-term` where can I find this information?

Answer (score 2):

For GNU ELPA, the information is available via http://elpa.gnu.org/packages (this includes both a link to the home site as well as the NEWS section, for those (fairly rare) packages which include one).  The package.el that will come with Emacs-24.4 will be able to show you the URL of the home site (at least for GNU ELPA packages, but I expect MELPA and Marmalade will also offer it soon if they don't already offer it).

Comment: MELPA doesn't yet support this, but is working on it, see https://github.com/milkypostman/melpa/issues/1233.  I do not think that Marmalade will ever support it.  The archive seems pretty dead.

Comment: Meanwhile, [melpa-upstream-visit](http://melpa.milkbox.net/#/melpa-upstream-visit) provides a workaround.