# In emacs who is setting Info-directory-list when including packages?

Tags: emacs, path, initialization, package-managers, info

I recently switched to the use of emacs' package manager [`packages`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Packages.html).

Since then, some emacs path variables get set beyond what I do in my `.emacs` file: Both `load-path` and `Info-directory-list` get perpended with stuff from the packages. But I don't understand *where* these customisations are done.

Let's concentrate on `Info-directory-list`: In my `.emacs` file I don't set it so it should be  nil (so that later when `info` starts up, its initialised from `Info-default-directory-list`. However with my new packaging it is already intialised and some package directories are added. This messes up my `dir` structure in `info`. I have checked the autoload files, but they don't set `Info-directory-list` in any way - and no other elisp file in the packages (`pandoc-mode` in particular) do so.

Where is the `Info-directory-list` variable set and how can I regain control over the order in this variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After evaluating your init file, Emacs calls `package-initialize` (which does what it sounds like). After initializing the packages, Emacs runs `after-init-hook`, so if you want to manipulate variables which have been modified during package initialisation, you can put the following in your init file:

```el
(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'my-after-init-hook)
(defun my-after-init-hook ()
  "After package initialisation."
  ;; do something with Info-directory-list
  )
```

You can also call `package-initialize` yourself, provided that you ensure that any necessary package-related variables are set beforehand. See [Emacs 24 Package System Initialization Problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127109/emacs-24-package-system-initialization-problems/18783152#18783152) for details.

As for how and why `Info-directory-list` is being modified, the manual comments on that aspect in `(elisp) Multi-file Packages`:

> A multi-file package is less convenient to create than a single-file
>   package, but it offers more features: it can include multiple Emacs
>   Lisp files, an Info manual, and other file types (such as images).

[...]

> If the content directory contains a file named `dir`, this is
>   assumed to be an Info directory file made with `install-info`.  *Note
>   Invoking install-info: (texinfo)Invoking install-info.  The relevant
>   Info files should also be present in the content directory.  In this
>   case, Emacs will automatically add the content directory to
>   `Info-directory-list` when the package is activated.

Specifically, `package-activate-1` does this:

```el
(when (file-exists-p (expand-file-name "dir" pkg-dir))
      ;; FIXME: not the friendliest, but simple.
      (require 'info)
      (info-initialize)
      (push pkg-dir Info-directory-list))
```

Comment: ps: I had suspected `package-initialize` to be the culprit, so I commented it out in my .emacs file, but I didn't know that emacs calls it in any case...

Comment: @halloleo @phils Any idea why `Info-directory-list` contains many entries of the same package? E.g. I have 8 entries for `.emacs.d/elpa/magit-20150608.1139`.