# (message "%S" load-path) and (describe-variable load-path) give different results

Tags: emacs, elisp

`(message "%S" load-path)` and     `(describe-variable 'load-path)`
 give different results.
Several more path like `"/Users/updogliu/.emacs.d/elpa/flycheck-20140323.828"` appeared in the latter.

How can I make `(require 'flycheck)` use the "describe" one `load-path`?

Comment: if you can reproduce it (different values from `message` and `describe-variable`) with `emacs -Q`, please report it as a bug using `report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: Did you call `package-initialize` in your `init.el`?

Comment: You need to understand why describe-variable and message are returning different results. The most likely explanation that I can see is that load-path has a buffer-local value and that you are running describe-variable and message from different buffers. But until you can answer why this is happening (and you have not given enough information), no one can answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To setup Flycheck properly, you do not need to `require` Flycheck.  Instead, just enable Global Flycheck Mode:

```
(add-hook 'after-init-hook #'global-flycheck-mode)
```

This will enable Flycheck for all supported languages.

To make `(require 'flycheck)` work in your `init.el`, you need to add `(package-initialize)` at the *very beginning* of your `init.el`.

`(package-initialize)` sets up Emacs' built-in package system, which includes adding all packages to the `load-path`.  Emacs calls this automatically, but only **after** your `init.el` has been processed, hence the use of `after-init-hook` to enable Flycheck.

If you added a `message` call to your `init.el` without calling `(package-initialize)` first, you'll hence see the standard `load-path` without any of your packages.

To make your packages available in your `init.el` right away, you need to call `(package-initialize)` manually, at the beginning of your `init.el`.

Comment: This answer teaches a lot and solved my problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127109/emacs-24-package-system-initialization-problems