# Emacs 24.3 cannot find package (key-chord) during startup

Tags: emacs, raspbian

I have Emacs 24.3 running on Raspbian. I'm kind of enjoying running Emacs on Linux - seems to be a beter fit than on Windows. I installed the very useful `key-chord` package using the usual package functions. This results in a directory in `~\.emacs.d\elpa\key-chord-20080915.2156`.

Then I inserted the following in my init file:

```
(require 'key-chord)
(key-chord-mode 1)
```

This kicks out the following error:

```
File error: Cannot open load file, key-chord
```

However, if I hit `M-x` I can find all the key-chord functions and run key-chord mode and associated bits and pieces. What am I doing wrong...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emacs loads the installed packages *after* evaluating your init file. If you need your packages in your init file, you can use `(package-initialize)` to manually initialize the packages.

The reason you see some or all key-chord functions is that these functions are "autoloaded". You don't need a `require` to use these functions; in fact, the package is automatically loaded when you use such a function.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127109/emacs-24-package-system-initialization-problems before using `(package-initialize)` (but as olaf points out, there's no need for it in this instance).

Comment: Thank you for this. I put a `(package-initialize)` before the `key-chord` call and now it works fine.