# how to install a package on emacs that supports multiple cursors a'la sublime

Tags: emacs

I am new to emacs and am looking for an emacs package that supports multiple cursors a'la sublime. I have tried to install [magnars/multiple-cursors](https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el)  but without success. I can't even install the package directly. The following code does not work for me .

```
M-x package-install multiple-cursors
```

(emacs says `no match`, but in the `~/.emacs.d/elpa/archives/marmalade/archive-contents` file, I can find references to that package.)

I have the required repositories in init.el and also run `M-x package-refresh-contents`

```
(setq package-archives 
  '(("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
    ("marmalade" . "https://marmalade-repo.org/packages/")
    ("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/")))
```

I then installed the package via a package that requires it (in my case I installed `clj-refactor`, this brings in the dependency to `multiple-cursors`. When I eval `(require 'multiple-cursors)` I get the following error

```
File error: Cannot open load file, no such file or directory, multiple-cursors

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.
```

This is strange because in the folder `~/.emacs.d/elpa/multiple-cursors-20141026.503` contains the file `multiple-cursors.el`

I got very used to that sublime feature and would really appreciate to use multiple cursors in emacs. Has anyone has a similar problem with the mentioned package or knows how to solve it? A link to a similar package would also be appreciated.

Thank you

Edit:
I Use  [emacs for mac](http://emacsformacosx.com/) v24.3.1

Edit:

I have just noticed that I don't need to eval `(require 'multiple-cursors)`. The package is indeed installed (via the dependency) and I use it, great! The question remains why I can't directly install it.

Comment: It sounds like you're getting tripped up by

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127109/emacs-24-package-system-initialization-problems

Comment: I realize you want `package.el` to work correctly for you, but I just want to point out that it's possible to install `multiple-cursors` the old-fashioned way -- i.e., Github has a button on the webpage that says "Download ZIP", and you can extract the `*.el` files to your load-path (or create a new directory and add that new directory to your load-path); you can also clone the respository if you have Git installed on your computer.  `package.el` is nice when it works, but it is by no means necessary to use Emacs.