# Load and activate of Emacs package.el

Tags: emacs, emacs24, dot-emacs

I have something like (to be simplify)

```
(require 'package)

(setq package-archives
      '(("org"          . "http://orgmode.org/elpa/")
        ("melpa"        . "http://melpa.org/packages/")
        ("melpa-stable" . "http://stable.melpa.org/packages/")
        ("gnu"          . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")))

(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)
(package-initialize t)

(unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
  (package-refresh-contents)
  (package-install 'use-package))

(let ((default-directory (expand-file-name user-emacs-directory "elpa")))
 (normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path))

(require 'use-package)

(use-package helm
  :ensure t
  :commands (helm-M-x
         helm-mini
         helm-find-files
         helm-show-kill-ring)
  :init
  (add-hook 'after-init-hook 'helm-mode)

  :config
    (helm-autoresize-mode 1))
```

in my `.emacs`. But I was told that `Symbol's function definition is void: helm-mode` after startup emacs.

After reading the manual of [Packaging Basics](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Packaging-Basics.html#Packaging-Basics) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127109/emacs-24-package-system-initialization-problems), I find I still don't understand the mechanism of `package.el`.

I notice that the words `load` and `activate` are used in the manual, I suppose that `load` is 'Emacs adds the package’s content directory to load-path, and evaluates the autoload definitions in name-autoloads.el.' and `activate` is to 'fully `require`'. I know if I change `(package-initialize t)` into `(package-initialize)` everything will be fine.

I confirm that something like `"/Users/gaki/.emacs.d/elpa/helm-20160112.258"` is in `load-path` and `helm-mode` is `autoload`. Isn't it can be autoload and even in the `after-init-hook` ?

Comment: The question is not clear (to me). Could you clarify just what you are asking? If you are asking for an explanation of the package system then that is not a good fit for this site (which is generally for specific Q&A). It would be too broad to guess what is unclear to you and try to explain it. But if you can formulate a more specific question then perhaps it can stand.

Comment: You should not need to add the elpa directory (or its subdirectories) to the load-path, the package system will do that when correctly configured.

Answer (score 2):

A look at the code for `package-activate` and its helper `package-activate-1` shows that a package's autoloads file is not loaded unless the package has been 'activated'.

You've told Emacs not to activate any packages by using `(package-initialize t)`, and you've prevented it from activating them after loading your init file with `(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)`, so none of your package autoloads are known to Emacs.

I suggest changing `(package-initialize t)` to `(package-initialize)`.

Note that the documentation you linked to describes the `NO-ACTIVATE` argument as "for internal use only".

p.s. Activation does not `require` the package features -- there would be no purpose to the autoloads if it did -- so this should not take a very significant amount of time, unless perhaps you have a *really* large number of packages? What kind of time difference are you actually seeing here? (https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/19263/454 may help with answering that.)

Comment: Thanks for you answer ! I've believed that after `load`, the `load-path` will be set and `autoload` will be read and will be `fully require` if `activate`. Now I know emacs itself won't read the `autoload`s if `NO-ACTIVATE`. I try to speed up the emacs startup and the package `esup` told me that `(package-initialize)` is the bottleneck. After some Googling, I find that `(package-initialized t)` maybe a solution. But the `use-package` package seem will add `autoload` for items specified in `:commands`, `:bind`. Even I've added `helm-mode` in the `:commands` part, the error is still there.

Comment: I can't imagine any time-saving (surely very small?!) from preventing package activation will be worth the hassle of your packages not being correctly configured.