# emacs init.el auto-complete not working and is not installed

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, installation, spacemacs

I have gotten auto-complete to work before on emacs and for a while now, on spacemacs too. However, today while I was editing a .txt file I opened up spacemacs only to find this error:

Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/home/roy/.emacs.d/init.el':

File error: Cannot open load file, auto-complete

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.

I have tried everything I could find and yet the same problem ensues.

I install auto-complete M-x package-install [RET] auto-complete [RET] and restart spacemacs. Everything looks fine, except that auto-complete is not installed, so I install it again, but once I restart spacemacs then auto-complete is missing and I get the same error as the one above and the whole process repeats itself.

Here is what my init.el file looks like:

`;start package.el with emacs
(require 'package)
;add MELPA to repository list
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/"))
; initialize package.el
(package-initialize)
; start auto-complete with emacs
(require 'auto-complete)
(global-auto-complete-mode t)
; do default config for auto-complete
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(ac-config-default)`

Finally, there is another peculiar thing I have noticed. In my trash bin there are 3 folders of auto-complete that refuse to be deleted, also every time I reinstall auto-complete and restart spacemacs more auto-complete folders show up in my trash bin. I run Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS

How do I get auto-complete to stay and what's up with the trash bin?

Comment: Did you check if auto-complete.el is in your load-path. To display the contents of load-path you can run `C-h v` `load-path` `Enter`.

Comment: I launched spacemacs and searched through my load-path and it didn't appear, so then I installed auto-complete, and restarted emacs. Spacemacs booted up properly and I rechecked my load-path and found "/home/roy/.emacs.d/elpa/auto-complete-20160416.604" I closed spacemacs and restarted, but auto-complete was missing and the cycle continued

Comment: I fixed my issue by following this post [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127109/emacs-24-package-system-initialization-problems] and turning this: 'dotspacemacs-delete-orphan-packages t in my .spacemacs file to nil'

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue by following this post [stackoverflow.com/questions/11127109/… and turning this: 'dotspacemacs-delete-orphan-packages t in my .spacemacs file to nil'